# Map an array with attributes to array with differents attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

**Summary :**

I need to do something like that :

from :

```
[  {
      id: 1
      content: "hello"
      senderId: 1234
    },
    {
      id : 2
      content: "how are you"
      senderId: 1234
    },
]
```

to :

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        text: 'hello',
        user: {
            _id: 1234,
        },
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        text: 'how are you',
        user: {
            _id: 1234,
        },
    },
]
```

**Explanation:**

I'm very new to javascript (and 'new' javascript usages, like ES6). I'm writing an app on react native. I'm using mobx with firebase.

I have a MessageStore with @oberservable array of messages from firebase.

```
import {observable, computed} from 'mobx';
import {Fb} from '../firebase/firebase';
import {map, toJS} from 'mobx';
import {Config} from '../config/config';

class Message{
  id : string
  content : string
  senderId : string
}

class MessagesStore {
  @observable messages = []
  idConversation : string

  constructor(idConversation) {
    this.idConversation = idConversation
    Fb.messages.child(idConversation).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      value = snapshot.val();
      let message = new Message()
      message.id = value.id
      message.content = value.content
      message.senderId = value.senderId
      this.messages.push(message)
    });
  }

  @computed get allMessages(){
    return this.messages
  }

  @computed get json() {
    return toJS(this.messages);
  }
}
...
```

The thing is that I want to use in the UI a library for a chat (https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat)
and the state must be something like that :

```
  this.setState({
         messages: [
           {
             _id: 1,
             text: 'Hello developer',
             createdAt: new Date(),
             user: {
               _id: 2,
               name: 'React Native',
               avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
             },
           },
         ],
       })
    )
```

I placed this code in :

```
messagesStore.messages.observe(() => ...
```

My issue is : how to map my message array (messagesStore.messages) to the array needed by the lib. For example, I need to map my message attribute *content* to *text*, or *id* to *_id*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function :

```
var array1 = array2.map(function(obj){
  var rObj = {};
  rObj['_id'] = obj.id;
  rObj['text'] = obj.content;
  rObj['user'] = {};
  rObj['user']['_id'] = obj.senderId;
  return rObj;
})
```

**Edit 2 :**

Clean code with ES6 :

```
const array = array2.map(obj => { 
  const { id, content, senderId } = message; 
  return { 
    _id: id, 
    text: content, 
    user: { 
      _id: senderId
    } 
  }; 
});
```